# ImportError: No module named logger in rasa_nlu.server

Tags: python, logging, rasa-nlu

I am getting below error while trying to run

`python -m rasa_nlu.server -c sample_configs/config_spacy.json`

Can anyone help to solve this issue ?

Code:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
        exec code in run_globals
      File "/prdai/RasaAI/rasa_nlu-master/rasa_nlu/server.py", line 19, in <module>
        from rasa_nlu.data_router import DataRouter, InvalidProjectError, \
      File "rasa_nlu/data_router.py", line 19, in <module>
        from twisted.logger import jsonFileLogObserver, Logger
  Import Error: No module named logger
```

Comment: Hey I'd be happy to try and help, but can I get a bit more info. Are you running this on Windows, Mac, or Linux? How did you install Rasa: from pip or GitHub?

Comment: I am running this on Linux. I have changed python version to 3.4 so that it supports jsonFileLogObserver of twisted 17.9.0. Now it is working fine. Thanks Caleb :)

Comment: What version were you running, I’d recommend 2.7, 3.5, or 3.6 as those are the versions Rasa tests against.